# Message Passing variables for a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've read the message passing page repeatedly and tried multiple variations of it and I'm assuming I'm making a small mistake.

What I'm trying to do: I want to grab the background color of a page with a content script and then send that information to my popup (not a background page; I don't know if that matters) and then allow the popup to (simple example) write that variable in the popup.

Answer (score 2):

Content scripts run in the same process as the webpage (the "tab" process). Popups run in the same process as the background page (the "extension" process).

It sounds like you want the popup to send a request to the content script using `chrome.tabs.sendRequest`. The content script should be listening for requests using `chrome.extension.onRequest`.

Or, you might do it the other way around: the content script sends the request to the extension using `chrome.extension.sendRequest` and the popup listens for requests using `chrome.extension.onRequest`. When you send a request from a tab to the extension, any page in the extension process (popups or background) can listen for that request.

See the [message passing tutorial](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) which includes examples that you can copy and paste.

Comment: I tried using those specifics examples before and the problem I encountered was that it did write to the console log that the request was received; however, the popup did not write to the console log saying that the farewell was received.


Am I supposed to have the js file under content scripts (I currently do)?


Am I supposed to execute the js file through a background page or the popup (I currently am not)?

Comment: @Rhyono, You should have a content script and a script that is included in a <script> tag by the popup webpage. Or maybe I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: I do have those two. However it seems like the content script and popup aren't interacting. I don't see how it didn't work.

Comment: I figured the rest of the file would just be unnecessary noise while trying to explain it to me. So instead I made a new extension that is solely the message passing (which doesn't work still): https://gist.github.com/933685

Comment: I made some slight modifications to make it work. Refresh the webpage, right-click the empty popup icon and say Inspect popup, and it will run. https://gist.github.com/935129/

Comment: That works. However, most people aren't going to want to click "Inspect popup" in order to make the extension work. Why doesn't it work until inspected? And how can I make it work without being inspected?

Comment: You inspect it just to view the console.log output. I've modified the gist to show the response within the popup, so now you don't need to inspect it.

Comment: If the console.log for the farewell is in background.html you won't see it.

Comment: To see the console of a background page, go to chrome://extensions/, make sure the (+) Developer tools is expanded, and click on the link for the background page.